# How to create html block to display extra information on woocommerce single product page

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic

i am using this theme for [my website](http://bit.ly/1SbpXcE), it has tour booking facility with wocommerce, i am using external am using third party booking, they give me link & i simply paste it in each tour (product) page, i have few knowledge about wordpress, 
                    i simply want to put button link & other booking related information, could you help me to create post meta space on product page. theme designer given me this code

```
function adventure_tours_render_tour_booking_form( $product ) {
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return '';
    }

    return sprintf( '<div class="form-block block-after-indent"><a class="atbtn atbtn--secondary1" href="#sime_url_product_id_%d"></a></div>', $product->id, esc_html( $product->get_title() ) );
}
```

i used it in function.php in my child theme. but it has no function to put button link from product submit page ? for your example i created example in photoshop please have a look, really appreciate your co operation [image]

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you may need to add %s to the sprintf function, as the current link has no anchor text and this is supposed to be put in by sprintf as the second argument:

```
return sprintf( '<div class="form-block block-after-indent"><a class="atbtn atbtn--secondary1" href="#sime_url_product_id_%d">%s</a></div>', $product->id, esc_html( $product->get_title() ) );
```

Comment: thanks for reply 
i did it before, i dont want to post title, i want to create a html block to show price & short condition line, i am not using woocommerce price / variable. i will add price manually

Comment: on the woocommerce product page look for custom fields metabox (if it is not there turn it on via screen options at top of page) and add a key and value pair for each price / variable. then in your code you could just do something like:

Comment: $boxhtml = "<div>".get_post_meta($product->id,'customprice',true)."<br>".get_post_meta($product->id,'customcondition',true)."</div>"; return $boxhtml; 
((instead of return sprintf etc.))

Comment: thanks for reply 
i added the above code instead of return sprintf 

& created both custom field saved but its display only 'customprice' & 'customcondition' not working. plz have a look bit.ly/1OYhtVG

Comment: hard to tell without your actual code but there is <br class="customcondition"> there... you might have a typo, <br> is standalone line break... you want more like:

Comment: $boxhtml = "<div class='custombox'><div class='customprice'>".get_post_meta($product->id,'customprice',true)."</div><br><div class='customcondition'>".get_post_meta($product->id,'customcondition',true)."</div></div>"; return $boxhtml;

Comment: superb work well, I removed <br> still showing space under price

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34187/discussion-between-nisha-at-behance-and-majick).